# How to install new extension in Apache

Tags: php, apache, pspell

Hi friends i am using `Apache 2.4.4 (Win64)`, `PHP 5.4.12`. I need to install a new extension in it. I have a dll file of that extension i.e. `pspell.dll`. How should i make it work in my Apache? I have copied this dll to `apache/Apache2.4.4/bin/`. And enabled `extension=php_pspell.dll` in `apache/Apache2.4.4/bin/php.ini`. Restarted my apache but still getting no sign of this extension in `phpinfo();`. Please tell me what should i do?

Also getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function pspell_new()
```

Comment: try copying `pspell.dll` into `c:\windows\system32`

Comment: see http://us3.php.net/manual/en/pspell.installation.php

Answer (score 0):

Check server logs to see where is the problem.

Usually it's because file can't be found on disk or DLL file is not compatible with PHP - both PHP and DLL have to be compiled for same architecture, with same compiler and thread safety options.